# Slurm : invalid job credential

Tags: slurm, munge

I tried to set up a Slurm cluster, composed of one compute node and one control node.

Currently, launch some task doesn't work. The node sometime just become down even if the queue is not empty. Srun never work but sbatch yes.

```
#srun -N1 -l /bin/hostname
run: error: Task launch for StepId=28.0 failed on node toto2: Invalid job credential
srun: error: Application launch failed: Invalid job credential
srun: Job step aborted: Waiting up to 32 seconds for job step to finish.
```

I already set up the munge key with the good user, encode and decode is possible:

```
#munge -n | ssh slurm@toto2 unmunge
STATUS:           Success (0)
ENCODE_HOST:      toto2 (10.0.0.2)
ENCODE_TIME:      2023-09-29 11:23:31 +0200 (1695979411)
DECODE_TIME:      2023-09-29 11:23:31 +0200 (1695979411)
TTL:              300
CIPHER:           aes128 (4)
MAC:              sha256 (5)
ZIP:              none (0)
UID:              root (0)
GID:              root (0)
LENGTH:           0
```

sbatch work sometimes, but if the sbatch job doesn't start right away, the compute node could possibly become not responding, and I have to manually make it idle again, even if my node is available through SSH.

My munge service is:

```
#cat /lib/systemd/system/munge.service
[Unit]
Description=MUNGE authentication service
Documentation=man:munged(8)
After=network.target
After=time-sync.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/munged
PIDFile=/var/run/munge/munged.pid
User=munge
Group=munge
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In toto1 (the control node) slurmctl is started with:
User=slurm
In toto2 (the compute node) slurmctl is started with:
User=root

And of course, the UID/GID of slurm and munge user are the same between both node.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the UID/GID must match between all nodes for all users who can submit jobs, not only for the `slurm` user. If you submit jobs as `root`, also make sure that `DisableRootJobs` is not set in `slurm.conf`.

If UID/GID match, then you should investigate for a possible time drift between the nodes ; the munge credential include a timestamp and can be invalid if the nodes are not all aligned on the same NTP server. I have observed a small time drift can lead to a situation where some jobs run and some other in a seemingly random way, but most probably actually based on the resolution of the timestamp.

Comment: I want to submit job only with the user that already match their UID/GID, as root the DisableRootJobs is not enabled in my case.

In my case, time drift is not the very present:
root@toto1#clockdiff -o toto2
..
host=toto2 rtt=562(280)ms/0ms delta=-53ms/-53ms Fri Sep 29 15:07:35 2023

Do you think I need to set up a ntp server on toto1 and put toto2 as a client ?